# Automatically resizing UIButton height based on title - AutoLayout ON

Tags: ios, resize, uibutton, height, autolayout

Basically the title explains the problem. Working with XCode, I have this button and I populate its title with different text sources (some are long texts some are short). I just want that the button resizes dynamically with the content using Autolayout.

Things not working:

- `sizeToFit`;
- Setting a height constraint of >= x;
- setting the button's frame height = titleLabel height.

Nobody seems to know over the internet and I wonder how could it be possible? I think is one of the MOST COMMON FEATURES for a button.

Someone knows a way to help me? Am I doing something wrong with this idea? Is there some other way to achieve this?

Thank you to anyone who will answer. Really.

Comment: From you question, it seems to me that you want the button to have a static width and grow in height based on its title. As buttons have an intrinsic size, it should resize itself if you provide enough constraints that it knows where to draw it. It should be enough if you tell the button how wide it should be (fixed width constraint), and where it should be drawn on the x/y axis. If this is provided, autolayout should have enough info to calculate a custom height.

Comment: Unfortunately this approach doesn't work..but yes, you got the problem correctly!

Comment: Can you post the code for how you create the button and how you update its title? Auto-resizing to title length is the default behavior for buttons, but there may be something else in the way you've coded it that's preventing that.

Comment: The button is created directly in storyboard and I update its title using:  
    [self.risposta setTitle:[answers objectAtIndex:2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

where "answers" is an NSArray containing NSString objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found this solution:

```
NSAttributedString *text = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[self titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] attributes:nil];

CGRect rect = [text boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){287, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                                 options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                 context:nil];


NSLayoutConstraint *buttonConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                    constraintWithItem:self
                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem: nil
                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                    multiplier:1.0f
                                    constant:rect.size.height];

[self addConstraint:buttonConstraint];
```

Which works but ONLY ONE TIME. I mean: as soon as the new title populates the titleLabel it says that there is already a constraint and It doesn't work anymore...

Comment: In which case, store this constraint, and remove it and re add the new height constraint, whenever necessary. `[self removeConstraint:buttonConstraint]; (your old constraint)` and then add the new.

Answer (score -2):

you can do like this

```
CGSize stringsize = [myString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]]; 
//or whatever font you're using
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,stringsize.width, stringsize.height)];
```

Comment: No, the OP said "using autolayout". This does not solve the problem correctly

Comment: yes the problem is the autolayout indeed.
I would have already solved it otherwise.