# How to size UIButton to fit the text when it has constraints to another elements?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, interface-builder, constraints

The situation is on the image below:

[image]

Position of every element below UIButton depends on the position of the UIButton or the element located directly above.

How to size it properly?

In my code I set:

```
eventTitleButton.setTitle("verylong text, very long text, with some of text, there is os much text, that I cannot described it in a short way", forState: .Normal)
eventTitleButton.sizeToFit()
```

But the result is:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a bottom space constraint on the button to "time". How is "time" constrained?

Comment: Top space to UIButton = 10, and bottom Space to location = 10

Comment: It seems like the constraint will only update once and has to be removed and added back in. This seems odd but is the working solution in this similar question. You could define the constraint in the designer and give it an outlet instead of creating it in code. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22455099/automatically-resizing-uibutton-height-based-on-title-autolayout-on

Answer (score 0):

You could add constraints on the width and/or height of your UIButton. That way, it could have width and/or height >= x (x being the minimal size you want it to have).

Then, you should not even need to call sizeToFit().

Comment: No, it still keep its size without changes